# How I can take the number after the dot via substring?

Tags: swift, substring

I'm getting a value like this 264.8 and I want to take the value before and after the dot. I can take the value before the dot like this

```
var string = "264.8"
var index = string2.rangeOfString(".", options: .BackwardsSearch)?.startIndex
var substring = string.substringToIndex(index2!)
```

but please how I can take it after the dot?

Comment: `substringFromIndex`

Comment: Why do you use `.BackwardsSearch`? Will there be multiple dots?

Comment: Oh my God how I didn't see  substringFromIndex thanks @Wain

Comment: @Arc676 No there is only one dot.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
        var string = "264.8"
        var numbers = string.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
        print(numbers[0])
        print(numbers[1])
```

Comment: @CAN if this anwsers is what you looking for you should mark it.

Comment: `first` & `last` would likely be better options

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = "264.8"
let partsArr = string.componentsSeparatedByString(".")

var beforeDot: String = partsArr[0]
var afterDot: String? = partsArr[1]
```

Comment: There's no point in declaring `afterDot` as an optional.  If there was not a dot, this code crashes.

Comment: yes, but it easy to check the partsArr length to avoid this error. My code - it just the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, an alternative is to use `split`:

```
let string = "264.8"
let result = string.characters.split(".").map { String($0) }
print(result[0]) // "264"
print(result[1]) // "8"
```

And another one is to use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet`:

```
let string = "264.8"
let result = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet())
print(result[0]) // "264"
print(result[1]) // "8"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, define a closure variable that handles the conversion for you

```
let mySubstringClosure : (String) -> (String) = { $0.componentsSeparatedByString(".").first ?? $0 }

let substring1 = mySubstringClosure("264.8") // "264"
let substring2 = mySubstringClosure("264")   // "264"
let substring3 = mySubstringClosure("")      // ""
```

Note that this code runs safely even if no dot `.` exists in the string, or of the string is empty.